# Links don't open new page in Safari Iphone browser unless you hold and select Open/Open in New Page

Tags: wordpress, mobile-safari

I am working with a Wordpress site, and recently the links have become deprecated in the mobile Safari browser. None of the links will allow you to click through with the usual touch gestures, though the links animate as if they have been clicked. The user now must hold down the link until Safari's menu pops up and select 'open'. My question is what could be causing this, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens occasionally with WP themes that come bundled with other plugins. The plugins that come in these bundles sometimes do not update properly or at all until the theme developers update the theme, causing glitches and compatibility issues. Not all themes are created equal.